# how to modify Type in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, alter

I have a type defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE New_A AS
   (id integer,
    id_new integer,
    arrived date,
    sum numeric);
```

I would like to change `arrived` from `date` type to  `timestamp without time zone` type

I tried:

```
ALTER TYPE New_A SET arrived TO timestamp without time zone
```

but it doesn't work. it gives:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "arrived"

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertype.html

Comment: I read this. there is no example how to change the type. read it carefully... they say "SET DATA TYPE" but there are no examples. eveything I try generate same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `alter attribute` clause:

```
ALTER TYPE new_a ALTER ATTRIBUTE arrived TYPE timestamp without time zone;
```

For the full details, please refer to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertype.html).